# Adding a date view to Objects in Rails

Tags: date, view

how do you view objects by day with rails?

I have an advertisers MVC and am currently listing advertisers created. I'd like to generate a view of advertisers for particular days - so you can choose the day on a calendar icon and see the advertisers added on that specific day.

I appreciate any help you guys can give - or pointing me in the right direction...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just order by date, that's a relatively simple solution (mock code obviously since I don't have access to your app, change variables to match your reality). In your controller action for index:

```
@advertisers = Advertiser.order(:date)
```

where 'date' would be your column name. You can add ASC or DESC to control ascending or descending.

```
@advertisers = Advertiser.order(date: :asc)
```

More on this here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering

In the specific case above, it sounds like you only want to show those that MATCH the particular date in question. I would set this up as an AJAX request when you click on the date in the view file. You could pass this to a Advertiser.find_by date: (or find_by_date in pre v4) kind of approach.

```
Advertiser.find_by date: '2013-11-13'
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-a-single-object

Something along those lines should get you on the right path.